# How to correctly create and fetch Core Data entities using .onTapGesture within a NavigationLink

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm still learning SwiftUI and CoreData and I'm working on a dummy project where essentially I'm trying to create a User Entity on the SignUp View, then upon clicking the SignUp Button, I would like to sequentially Create and Fetch the User data in order to display it inside of my ContentView. I came up with a way to do it, but I'm sure that it's the incorrect way since when I create a new Object, it also creates a bunch of NULL data along with it and I suspect that it's because I'm not giving the UI enouygh time to create, fetch, and display the data in the view. Here is the code I'm working with...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    NavigationLink(
        destination: getDestination(from: admin),
        isActive: self.$isSignUpValid){
        Text("Sign Up")
            .onTapGesture {
                createUserObject(company: self.company, name: self.name, username: self.username, password: self.password, photo: self.inputImage, admin: self.admin)
                selectedUser = fetchUserDetails(withUser: username)
                self.selectedImageArray = imagesFromCoreData(object: selectedUser!.photo!)!
                isSignUpValid = true
            }
    }
    


        //Sets appropriate View destination based on value of Admin variable.
            func getDestination(from adminValue: Bool) -> AnyView {
                
                    if adminValue == false {
                        return AnyView(ContentView(selectedUser: self.selectedUser ?? User(context: moc), selectedImageArray: self.selectedImageArray))
                    }
                    else {
                        return AnyView(AdminView(selectedUser: self.selectedUser ?? User(context: moc), selectedImageArray: self.selectedImageArray))
                    }
                }


func createUserObject(company: String, name: String, username: String, password: String, photo: UIImage?, admin: Bool){
    
    //Produces a Data object from an Array of Images.
    func coreDataObjectFromImages(image: UIImage) -> Data? {
        let dataArray = NSMutableArray()
        
        if let data = image.pngData() {
            dataArray.add(data)
        }
        return try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dataArray, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    }
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    let newUser = User(context: context)
    newUser.id = UUID()
    newUser.admin = admin
    newUser.company = company
    newUser.name = name
    newUser.username = username
    newUser.password = password
    newUser.photo = coreDataObjectFromImages(image: (photo ?? UIImage(systemName:"person.circle")!))
    
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("New User Created")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}



func fetchUserDetails(withUser user: String) -> User? {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username == %@", user)
    
    do {
        let fetchUser = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return fetchUser.first
    } catch let fetchError {
        print("Failed to fetch: \(fetchError)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: please could you provide more detail about what you mean when you say it is creating a bunch of NULL data. Is it creating more than one user? or is it creating one user but the values within the record are null?

Comment: In addition to creating the User entity that it's supposed to create, it's also creating multiple (about 20) Users Entities with NULL assigned to all its properties.

Comment: Hmmmm not sure. Have you added breakpoints to see if your functions are getting called multiple times?

Comment: I figured it out. It was calling the getDestination function every time the SignUp view would appear and it would add a new via User(context: moc) to the context without committing. Then when I push the SignUp Button, it would commit the multiple users. But now I'm trying to figure out how to set destination to the ContentView without having to use a nil coalescing operator to pass the fetched data to the next view without it returning nil.

Comment: Could you declare your variable in ContentView to be an optional and then pass nil if there is no selected user. Or if you don’t want to add the empty user to the context then I believe you can just pass User() in your nil coalescing operator.